# notifyDataSetChanged() method does not work

Tags: android

I have created one application in that I have created a custom listview. When user click the download button which is present in custom listview then file will be downloaded then I want to disable or hide that button and I am able to hide that button but when user press back and come again then the button hide but I want when user click the download button and file should be downloaded then immediately hide that button.
This is the code of my custom list adapter

```
     @Override
              public View getView(final int position, View convertView,  
              ViewGroup parent) 
            {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"DroidSans-Bold.ttf");
            holder.textViewName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            holder.textViewurl = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUrl);
           holder.download = convertView.findViewById(R.id.downloadimage);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
      holder.textViewName.setText(pdfList.get(position).getName());
      holder.textViewurl.setText(pdfList.get(position).getUrl());
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                + "android"+"/"+"data"+"/"+"foldername"+"/"+ pdfList.get(position).getName()+".pdf");
        if(file.exists())
        {
            holder.download.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        else
        {
            holder.download.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(position);
                }
            });

        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return convertView;

    }
```

Comment: can you show download code

Comment: You have to call the notifyDataSetChanged(); inside the button click callback.
Currently you have added the notifyDataSetChanged() inside the getView() which is wrong. Please do not do that.

Comment: What exactly you trying to notify inside `getView()`? the code you have written is a disaster . Call  `notifyDataSetChanged();` only on some action .

Comment: Never called  `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your `getView()` , it is very bad because `getView()` is called each time when you scroll the listview, you have to called the `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside the button click  .
And if you want to change only one view than you can use `notifyItemChanged(position)`  instead of `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your notifyDataSetChanged() is at the wrong position, try to call it on your download button click.

```
 @Override
          public View getView(final int position, View convertView,  
          ViewGroup parent) 
        {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
        Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"DroidSans-Bold.ttf");
        holder.textViewName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        holder.textViewurl = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUrl);
       holder.download = convertView.findViewById(R.id.downloadimage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
  holder.textViewName.setText(pdfList.get(position).getName());
  holder.textViewurl.setText(pdfList.get(position).getUrl());
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
            + "android"+"/"+"data"+"/"+"foldername"+"/"+ pdfList.get(position).getName()+".pdf");
    if(file.exists())
    {
        holder.download.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
    else
    {
        holder.download.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }
    return convertView;

}
```